How to get video file duration from video URL
I am working on a C# application where I need to get the duration of a video file from a given URL. The video files are hosted online, and I need to fetch their durations programmatically.
I’ve searched online but haven’t found a clear solution for doing this in C#. Most of the examples I found deal with using 3rd party libraries. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this without any library?
Here is what I’ve tried so far:
MediaInfo Library:
FFMpeg:
HttpClient:
Code Snippet:
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
   static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
       string videoUrl = "https://example.com/video.mp4";
       using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
       {
           HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(videoUrl);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               
               byte[] videoData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
               
           }
       }
   }
}


Just something to consider:

which video formats must be supported
of course don't know the big picture, but keep in mind that your initial approach would mean that 1st every video must be transfered to the system where your code runs.


There are two ways I can suggest you to get the video duration  of a video file from URL.

Using C#
Using Javascript (In case of a web application and you want it be generated on the fly)

Using C# (Need to include shell object dll)
string VideoDuration = string.Empty;

Thread thread = new Thread(() => { VideoDuration = GetVideoDuration(videoPath.Replace("/", "\\")); });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
thread.Abort();

[STAThread] // Add STAThread attribute here
public static string GetVideoDuration(string filepath)
{
    string formatedduration = "";

    // Create Shell32 Shell object
    Shell shell = new ShellClass();

    // Get the folder that contains the video file
    Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath));

    // Get the video file
    FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath));

    // Get the duration property
    string duration = folder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, 27); // 27 is the index of the "Duration" property

    formatedduration = GetTimeFormat(duration);

    return formatedduration;
}


private static string GetTimeFormat(string timeformat)
{

    // Split the time format string into hours, minutes, and seconds
    string[] parts = timeformat.Split(':');

    // Parse hours, minutes, and seconds
    int hours = int.Parse(parts[0]);
    int minutes = int.Parse(parts[1]);
    int seconds = int.Parse(parts[2]);

    // Construct TimeSpan object
    TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);

    string formattedTime = "";

    if (timeSpan.Hours != 0)
    {
        formattedTime += $"{hours}hr{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")} ";
    }
    if (timeSpan.Minutes != 0)
    {
        formattedTime += $"{minutes}min";
    }
    if (timeSpan.Seconds != 0)
    {
        formattedTime += $"{seconds}sec";
    }

    return formattedTime;
}

Using Javascript
<video id="videoId" width="1920" height="1080" controls>
  <source src="yourVideoURL.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
let videoTag = document.getElementById("videoId");
alert(vidTag.duration);
</script> 

